# Downloading through Safari on the Command Line?

Tags: macos, safari

I tried Googling this - and none of the answers was a sufficient match to my question.

I need a command line that will download a file through Safari.

The download **must** be triggered and directed from the command line - - or else I will not be able to integrate it into a broader script.

Due to the purpose of this script, the file **must** be downloaded. No browser window opened to the file - nothing of that sort. Simply download the file to the location that I direct in the command line.

The download **must** use Safari - because Safari is logged on to my Google account, while other programs (such as **curl**) are not, and therefore will not be *able* to download the file that I need downloaded.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate with google using Curl, I think this would me much easier than trying to download something through safari, take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL) guide.